# Difference between %% and % in R

Tags: r

What is the difference between `%%` and `%` in the **R** programming language?

I am getting the following result:

```
> 5%%2
[1] 1
> 5%2
Error: unexpected input in "5%2"
```

where can we use a single `%` in **R**?

Comment: There is no single `%` in R.  `help("%")#
No documentation for ‘%’ in specified packages and libraries:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `R` , there is no `%`.  We can find it from

```
help(`%`)
```

> No documentation for ‘%’ in specified packages and libraries: you
>   could try ‘??%’

Answer (score 2):

In R `%%` gives remainder of first vector with the second as follows a example.

```
first <- c( 2,5.5,6)
second <- c(8, 3, 4)
print(first%%second)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
[1] 2.0 2.5 2.0
```

As already mentioned by akrun sir in comments there is nothing like `%` in R.